# Explorer MP3 thumbnail not updating when saved with TagLib#

Tags: c#, mp3, taglib, taglib-sharp

I am using `TagLib#` to edit some `MP3` tags. To set the album art for the track, I use the following simple line:

```
file.Tag.Pictures = new TagLib.IPicture[] { new TagLib.Picture(filepath) };
```

It works and sets the image as expected. When I save the file, close the program and load up the file again, I correctly see the image I assigned. Clearly, it wrote the image to the file.

But when I look at the file in `Windows Explorer`, it does not show the correct icon I set, instead showing the default one. Only when I re-save the file in `Tagscan` does the icon update, and then modifying the image from my program begins changing the icon to match what was saved.

**What is the issue here? How can I allow my image changes to be shown as a thumbnail without having to use another program?**

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Here's some more information discovered along the way. I saved an image in a plain `MP3` and looked at it in `Notepad`, then re-saved the file with `Tagscan` and took another look to see what changed. Here's the data I found.

- No image, untouched:

`ID3 TXXX major_brand isom TXXX minor_version 512 TXXX compatible_brands isomiso2mp41 TSSE Lavf57.51.102 TIT2 test nameTALB test albumTPE2 test artistTCOM test artistTPE1 test artistPRIV SampleStart 0 0 : 0 0 : 0 0`

- Image added with my program:

`ID3 TXXX major_brand isom TXXX minor_version 512 TXXX compatible_brands isomiso2mp41 TSSE Lavf57.51.102 TIT2 test nameTALB test albumTPE2 test artistTCOM test artistTPE1 test artistPRIV SampleStart 0 0 : 0 0 : 0 0 APIC Q  image/png  ‰PNG IHDR óÿa ‹IDATxœcÀ0¹õ¿yz÷ëÜ~8‰°jxõ‚ø7.ÿŸ;ÿðÿØþÍÿ£{7ÿÏž{ŒAâ¦é½Ä Ò3 †Aâæ™D ²=°y%ŠÈ® h H¡¤{&Ã4ÂøD RÓhœØÆ0~ëjÂ€ÁlDÇD¹ d ÌFd'Ê#  1šY¬Œß IEND®B‚`

- File with image re-saved with Tagscan:

`ID3    TXXX     major_brand isom TXXX     minor_version 512 TXXX      compatible_brands isomiso2mp41 TSSE     Lavf57.51.102 TIT2           TXXX   %  ÿþm a j o r _ b r a n d   ÿþi s o m TXXX   '  ÿþm i n o r _ v e r s i o n   ÿþ5 1 2 TXXX   A  ÿþc o m p a t i b l e _ b r a n d s   ÿþi s o m i s o 2 m p 4 1 TSSE     ÿþL a v f 5 7 . 5 1 . 1 0 2 TIT2     ÿþt e s t   n a m e TALB     ÿþt e s t   a l b u m TPE2     ÿþt e s t   a r t i s t TCOM     ÿþt e s t   a r t i s t TPE1     ÿþt e s t   a r t i s t PRIV     SampleStart 0 0 : 0 0 : 0 0 APIC   Ñ   image/png  ‰PNG  IHDR óÿa ‹IDATxœcÀ0¹õ¿yz÷ëÜ~8‰°jxõ‚ø7.ÿŸ;ÿðÿØþÍÿ£{7ÿÏž{ŒAâ¦é½Ä Ò3 †Aâæ™D ²=°y%ŠÈ® h H¡¤{&Ã4ÂøD RÓhœØÆ0~ëjÂ€ÁlDÇD¹ d ÌFd'Ê#  1šY¬Œß IEND®B‚`

The only noticeable change is that everything got... spaced out. I realize poking through the song data in Notepad of all things probably isn't the best way to find information, but it's the best I've got.

Comment: Might not be the cause of the issue but ensure you save with ID3 version <= 2.3. Windows Explorer shows a default file icon for 2.4 tags. I think the spacing is automatically compensated for, so the tag version would be my best guess.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much! I swapped out the `TagLib.Id3v2.Tag.DefaultVersion` to `3` and it did the trick. That's so weird that Explorer does that, but thanks for letting me know!

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll mark it right, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Well, I have posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you save with ID3 version <= 2.3.
Windows Explorer shows the default file icon associated with the `.mp3` extension for 2.4 tags.

`ID3v2.4`, though being around for a while now, is not really the most compatible version of ID3 to use. Windows Explorer and Groove Music alike don't recognize tags saved with that version. I think Google Play Music too has this issue.

So, your safest bet would be to store tags using `ID3v2.3`.